# How to parse a string using a string specification?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, regex-group, regex-greedy

I wish to write a method to parse strings containing the names of people and their ages. For example:

```
Manuel 8
Mustafa 16
Zhihao 12
Itsuki 12
Louis 11
Farah 11
```

i.e. the specification of the strings is `%N %A`, where `%N` represents the name, and `%A` represents the age.

However, the specification of the strings is not fixed (e.g. it could be `%N age:%A` or `%N (%A)` in another document), so the parsing method should be able to take the specification as one of its arguments.

In other words, the parsing method should work like this:

```
Data d1 = Parser.parse("Indira 15", "%N %A");
Data d2 = Parser.parse("12 Shu-chen", "%A %N");
Data d3 = Parser.parse("Hana (12)", "%N (%A)");
Data d4 = Parser.parse("Name: Sophia [12]", "Name: %N [%A]");
```

where `Data` and `Parser` are defined like this:

```
public class Data {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Data(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    // + getter and setter methods.
}

public class Parser {
    public static Data parse(String s, String specification) {
        // --- What to do here? ---
        return (new Data(name, age));
    }
}
```

How can `Parser.parse` be written? In other words, how can a string be parsed using a string specification?

Comment: Keyword: `Regular Expression`

Comment: @RickyMo Yes I know how to use regex to parse a string that has a fixed specification, but I am not exactly sure how to parse a string that has a variable specification.

Comment: You can use capture group to capture the variable. Use `(.+)` for `%N` and `([0-9]+)` for `%A` and retrieve the captured group using `Matcher.group()` in Java. Example Regex : [https://regexr.com/4dgev](https://regexr.com/4dgev). However, you may need to do extra analysis to determine whether age come first or name come first.

Comment: Is this what you mean:  that the "specification" _literally_ spells out the format, with only `%N` and `%A` for name/age?   Then do exactly that: form the regex out of the `specification`, in which you replace `%N` with `([\w-']+)` (add whatever else may be in a name, or use `[^0-9]+`) and `%A` with `([0-9]+)`.  Then when you match on the `s` with this you'll get the name and age captured.  To see which is which consult your specification again (was `%N` or `%A` the first one?).

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can have an expression and collect our desired outputs in two groups, such as:

```
((?:\s+)?([a-z-]+)(?:\s+)?)|(\d+)
```

where our desired names are in this `([a-z-]+)` group, and the age info are in this `(\d+)` and the rest can be simply scripted.

#### TEST

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "((?:\\s+)?([a-z-]+)(?:\\s+)?)|(\\d+)";
final String string = "Indira 15\n"
     + "12 Shu-chen\n"
     + "Hana (12)\n"
     + "Sophia [12]\n"
     + "  Manuel 8\n"
     + "Mustafa  16\n"
     + "Zhihao    12\n"
     + "Itsuki 12\n"
     + "Louis 11\n"
     + "Farah 11";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/UI5Xte/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/j9rWYa/1/)

#### Advices

Based on [zdim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653379/zdim)'s advice:

> (1) I think that (?:\s+)? (at least one space, but the whole thing is
>   optional) is the same as \s* (optional spaces)
>
> (2) In the second group of spaces I think that you want to require at
>   least a space, so just \s+.

We can much simplify and modify our initial expression to something similar to:

```
(\s*([a-z-]+)\s+)|(\d+)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Xf7gyC/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Are you sure this method will work with a string like `* Name: John; Age: 15` (string specification: `* Name: %N; Age: %A`?

Comment: @Flux  Well, no, it won't (is that a real asterisk there ??).  What you are asking is extremely broad, effectively for a general-purpose parser. (Note that you haven't given a definitive list of patterns to support.)   That would take a whole lot more code than what is suitable for an SO post.  This answer would cover one of the cases (with little tweaks perhaps)

Answer (score 0):

I would read the specification and use it to parse off all parts of the string that are not between %N and %A as they just complicate your logic.  You then have to figure out what constraints you intend to put on this api as if you do not put constraints on it its non-deterministic.  For Example

H'mil99 is pattern %N%A but is the nam H'mil with age 99 or H'mil9 with age 9.

If you chose logical restrictions of no numerics in name and no alphas in age then a identify the age by doing a matcher.group on [0-9]*, sub-string it out along with the part between %A and %N and the rest is %N

Answer (score 0):

Build a regex from the `specification`, e.g. something like below.

Note the use of [`Pattern.quote()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) to ensure that special characters in the `specification` are not interpreted as regex.

```
public static Data parse(String s, String specification) {
    // Determine order of value markers
    int nameIdx = specification.indexOf("%N");
    if (nameIdx == -1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Specification is missing %N: " + specification);
    int ageIdx = specification.indexOf("%A");
    if (ageIdx == -1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Specification is missing %A: " + specification);

    // Build regex
    String regex;
    if (nameIdx < ageIdx) {
        regex = Pattern.quote(specification.substring(0, nameIdx)) + "(\\S+)" +
                Pattern.quote(specification.substring(nameIdx + 2, ageIdx)) + "(\\d+)" +
                Pattern.quote(specification.substring(ageIdx + 2));
    } else {
        regex = Pattern.quote(specification.substring(0, ageIdx)) + "(\\d+)" +
                Pattern.quote(specification.substring(ageIdx + 2, nameIdx)) + "(\\S+)" +
                Pattern.quote(specification.substring(nameIdx + 2));
    }

    // Parse string
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(s);
    if (! m.matches())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("String does not fit specification '" + specification + "': " + s);
    String name, age;
    if (nameIdx < ageIdx) {
        name = m.group(1);
        age = m.group(2);
    } else {
        name = m.group(2);
        age = m.group(1);
    }
    return new Data(name, Integer.parseInt(age));
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(parse("Indira 15", "%N %A"));
System.out.println(parse("12 Shu-chen", "%A %N"));
System.out.println(parse("Hana (12)", "%N (%A)"));
System.out.println(parse("Name: Sophia [12]", "Name: %N [%A]"));
```

*Output (assuming `toString()` implemented in `Data` class)*

```
Data[name=Indira, age=15]
Data[name=Shu-chen, age=12]
Data[name=Hana, age=12]
Data[name=Sophia, age=12]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for the data given and should work for other variations.  But other special characters may not be escaped properly.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Parser2 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Data d1 = Parser.parse("Indira 15", "%N %A");
      Data d2 = Parser.parse("12 Shu-chen", "%A %N");
      Data d3 = Parser.parse("Hana (12)", "%N (%A)");
      Data d4 = Parser.parse("Name: Sophia [12]", "Name: %N [%A]");

      System.out.println(d1);
      System.out.println(d2);
      System.out.println(d3);
      System.out.println(d4);

   }

}

class Data {
   private String name;
   private int    age;

   public Data(String name, int age) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
   }

   public String toString() {
      return "name = " + name + ", " + "age = " + age;
   }
}

class Parser {
   private static Map<String, String> spec =
         Map.of("%A", "(\\d+)", "%N", "([A-Za-z-]+)");

   public static Data parse(String s, String specification) {
      specification = specification.replaceAll("\\(", "\\\\(");
      specification = specification.replaceAll("\\)", "\\\\)");
      specification = specification.replaceAll("\\]", "\\\\]");
      specification = specification.replaceAll("\\[", "\\\\[");

      for (String r : spec.keySet()) {
         specification = specification.replace(r, spec.get(r));
      }

      Matcher m = Pattern.compile(specification).matcher(s);
      String m1 = "", m2 = "";
      if (m.find()) {
         m1 = m.group(1);
         m2 = m.group(2);
      } else {
         return null;
      }
      String name;
      int age;
      if (m1.matches("\\d+")) {
         age = Integer.parseInt(m1);
         name = m2;
      }
      else {
         age = Integer.parseInt(m2);
         name = m1;
      }

      return (new Data(name, age));
   }
}
```

- The () and [] are escaped to allow for your examples to work as they
  are special characters for regex.
- One of the captured strings needs to be tested for all digits to
  allow proper conversion for the name and age.
- This is a rather brute force approach and it does not scale well.